# Check Network Connection In a fragment with multiple asyntask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

what is the best way for checking network connection , when more than one asyntask should be run in a fragment. Is it better handle it in OncreateView method and check network for each async with multiple if statements Or handle network connection in each async task and use try/catch  in their doInBackground  ?? 
Thanks .

Comment: What are you trying to do? Does an AsyncTask rely on the previous one succeeding for it to work properly? Depending on how each AsyncTask works with each other will determine the proper answer for this question.

Comment: actually, no specific relation between AsyncTasks . just in each async some data received from json string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comment, I would check for network connection before creating and starting the AsyncTask.

That said, because you have a network connection when you start the AsyncTask does not guarantee you will have a network connection during the entire life of the AsyncTask, so handle errors elegantly in your AsyncTask.

And when your fragment is destroyed make sure to cancel and null out your AsyncTasks. Otherwise, your AsyncTasks will keep your fragment instance around in memory longer than you'd like since your fragment will likely have a strong reference to the AsyncTask and your AsyncTask will have a strong reference to the Fragment calling it via some interface or just a direct reference to the Fragment.

Also, if your AsyncTask calls back to a detached fragment that will most likely throw an exception when you run your post-AsyncTask code.

Answer (score -1):

Well first of i believe its way smarter to use AsyncTask within service, otherwise you can easily "lose" AsyncTask and just wasting jobs its doing not to mention how easy it is to cause memory leak with it.

You have to handle errors within AsyncTask otherwise your app will crash. So its kinda self explanatory :) It would also depend if you are trying to connect with different services or if one AsyncTask  requires other to be completed and so on and so on.

Comment: If an AsyncTask is used only for displaying information on a Fragment/Activity why would you push it into a Service?

Comment: Then check out what happens when you rotate device or leave and return to your app :) You have to handle many things that way. Its so easy to cause memory-leaks.

Comment: Yes, but those cases can be handled in the fragment.